# useEffect causing an infinite render loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm using react useEffect to get data from my backend, but it spams my terminal with the same message non-stop.

My code

```js
function DataFetching() {

    let [posts, setPosts] = useState([]); 

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/zoom')
            .then(res => {
                setPosts(res.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    })
```

The spam message I get on terminal

````
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `subject`, `MEETINGID`, `Password`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `data` AS `data`;```
````

Answer (score 2):

`setPosts()` is causing `DataFetching` to re-render, and because your `useEffect()` doesn't declare a dependencies list, it evaluates the effect after *every* render, so you've essentially coded an asynchronous infinite loop.

Your effect only depends on `setPosts()`, so you should declare that as the only dependency. Or, recognizing that `setPosts()` is already memoized by React, declare no dependencies at all:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/zoom').then(res => {
    setPosts(res.data);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}, [/*setPosts*/]);
```